# Max Height as Percentage of Container

Tags: wpf, xaml

I want to display a leader board, with each row with a `MaxHeight` set as a percentage of the container space.

I'm currently using a `ItemsControl` to template the rows and display the data.

I understand that you can achieve something similar with a grid, but because a requirement is I don't know how many entries are in the leader board before runtime, I can't specify the `RowDefinitions` in XAML.

Is there a simple way to achieve what I'm trying to do? Without updating the RowDefinitions with C# at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do: set the ItemsPanel into UniformGrid and adjust the `Rows` or `Columns`

```
<ItemsControl ..... >
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <UniformGrid Rows="4"/> <!--will be divided into 4 rows, so 25% each item-->
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Above is just an example. You could just manipulate `Columns` count into 1 and let the `Rows` count to be as much as the items, etc.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a go